# Can't use break in the false part of the ternary operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, break, ternary-operator

Consider the following code just as an **example**:

This one works

```
i = 0
flag = false
while i < 10
    flag = true
    if flag
        i+=1
    else
        break
    end
end
```

But when turn If part into ternary operator like this

```
i = 0
flag = false
while i < 10
    flag = true
    if flag ? i+=1 : break
end
```

I get this errors:

```
ternary.rb:5: void value expression
ternary.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I know this code lacks of logic, but the current example is the best what I came up with to show you what I've encountered with.

Comment: 1. You have a frankenstein there. It's neither a valid if, nor a valid ternary expression. 2. Don't use break in a ternary operator.

Comment: Also, what's the actual question?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why I cant use break in the false part of the ternary operator

Comment: In the first example of your code, when did it go to `else` block as `flag` is always `true`

Comment: no you can't use `break`

Comment: Change `if flag ? i+=1 : break` to `flag ? i+=1 : break`

Comment: @OccamRazor: technically you can, but you shouldn't. Ternary operator is an expression. Both branches should return a value. Not one return a value, while the other does flow control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is syntax issue in your code.  You can't use `if` in ternary operator `?:` as can be seen in your code line `if flag ? i+=1 : break`

Here is one way of writing the code:
I have taken liberty to modify the code so that it illustrates that `break` can be used.

```
i = 0
flag = true
while i < 10
    flag = false if i > 5
    flag ? i+=1 : break
end

p i
#=> 6
```

Comment: yes, it works now, thank you! and also, I know that flag is always true and the code has no sense. I told that I used it just to show what I mean. And also, turned out that all the comments saying that you cant use break in tha ternary were false?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `break` in a ternary here. It makes hard-to-read code. People don't usually expect control flow keywords in expressions. Actually, looking at it, it's not clear why you would even *want to* use ternary. Its two branches are completely unrelated.

If you're after clear compact code, consider using early break. Something like this:

```
while i < 10
  keep_processing = compute_flag # your logic here
  break unless keep_processing

  i += 1
end
```