# Mutate numbers in arrays

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined

I'm trying to writing something that allow "1s" in array can blur other number above, below and next to it. For example, if

```
image = Image.new([
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0]
])
```

the output would be:

```
0100
1110
0111
0010
```

So I write some code as below:

```
class Image
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def output_image
    @data.each do |pixel_row|
      pixel_row.each do |pixel_value|
        print pixel_value
      end

      print "\n"
    end
  end

  def blur
    ###find the location of "1"#######
    @data.each_with_index do |row, row_position|
      row.each_with_index do |pixel, col_position|
        if pixel == 1
          #left
          @data[row_position][col_position-1] = 1 if col_position > 0
          #right
          @data[row_position][col_position+1] = 1 if col_position < @data[row_position].length - 1
          #above
          @data[row_position-1][col_position] = 1 if row_position > 0
          #below
          @data[row_position+1][col_position] = 1 if row_position < @data.length - 1
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

image = Image.new([
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
])
image.output_image
image.blur
```

Currently my problem is number next to 1s and below to 1s would all turn to be 1s.

Comment: I changes method 'blur' the error gone. But blur didn't work.

if col_position > 0
if col_position < @data[row_position].length - 1
if row_position > 0
if row_position < @data.length - 1

Comment: How have you tried to debug this?  One way I frequently approach something like this is to walk through a few test cases on pen and paper (e.g. row_position == 1, col_position == 2) and read each line of code to see if the code I have written is doing what I want (ie pretend to be the computer).  I think you'll spot a bug:)

Comment: I'm willing to bet money that it is an out-of-bounds error when you do `row_position+1` or `col_position + 1`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for your reply! You hit the point. I'm now facing problems on these two lines

Comment: @Julie thank you. Your suggestion helps. I'm gradually solve some error and keep going for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you are trying to do, you can do something like below.

1. First find the co-ordinates where `1` is present
2. Then make a list of the co-ordinates adjacent to those - vertically or horizontally - as required by problem statement.  If (x,y) is given co-ordinate, then its adjacent co-ordinates on left will be (x-1, y), on right will be (x, y+1, above will be (x, y-1) and below will be (x, y+1)
3. While determining adjacent co-ordinates, ensure that you stay within the bounds - if we consider `image` to be a 2-D array, then, its dimensions are `image.length` x `image.first.length`. `image.first` returns first element of `image` array.  In the sample run below, the `image` is of dimension `4 x 4`
4. Update the `image` array and set the value to `1` to all the co-ordinates identified as being adjacent to ones having value `1`.

Below is the code for above logic

```
# A helper method to display the image as grid
def display(ary, msg)
    puts msg if msg
    ary.each do |i| 
        puts i.join(" ")
    end
end

def blur(image)
    # Co-ordinates of all 1's
    pos = []
    image.each_with_index do |arr, i|
        arr.each_with_index do |ele, j|
           pos << [i, j] if ele == 1
        end
    end

    # Adjacent co-ordinages
    adj_pos = pos.flat_map {|i, j| [[i,j+1],[i+1,j],[i-1,j],[i,j-1]] }
                   .reject do |i,j|  # Reject out-of-bounds co-ords
                       i < 0 || 
                       i >= image.length || 
                       j < 0 || 
                       j >= image.first.length 
                    end

    # Update to image
    adj_pos.each {|i, j| image[i][j] = 1}
end


image = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]


display(image, "Before blur")
blur(image)
display(image, "After blur")
```

Output of program

```
Before blur
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
After blur
0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0
```

For the above example run:

1. Value of `pos` will be `[[1, 1], [2, 2]]` which are two co-ordinates where `1` is present.
2. Value of `adj_pos` will be `[[1, 2], [2, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]]`.

Comment: This doesn't really helps him find the error in _his_ code, does it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I took a [cue from this answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34136455/794242) and thought may be I can offer a (relatively) cleaner solution.  Let me know if I am missing some SO guidelines, I do not dwell much in meta sections so I am novice at this

Comment: It seems to me that Ken is more interested in finding why _his_ code doesn't work, rather than have someone hand him complete solution. Your solution is nice/clean, but I think it's too early for Ken to fully comprehend it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for understanding my side. I hope I could understand more about the answer from Wandm Maker. I'm still too new in ruby on rails.

Answer (score -1):

The way the if on `#blur` was implemented is causing your bug:

```
#below
@data[row_position+1][col_position] = 1 if row_position == @data.length - 1
```

Note that your check `row_position == @data.length - 1` will return true even if you already are reading the last line of your `Array`, which is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

In your example. So this line will try to set a number `1` on a inexistent line (the next one after the last). Makes sense?

To change this line to:

```
#below
@data[row_position+1][col_position] = 1 if row_position == @data.length - 2
```

Will solve this bug. But I think (I'm not sure because I'm not in a terminal right now) that you will find other bugs similar to this one.

Comment: "Will solve this bug" - nah. It will transform it into another. Now the logic doesn't work correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot Ricardo. After I change the code like what I just post, the method error was solved.